# Is there any way to use my old Logitech Quickcam Express on Catalina?

Tags: catalina, webcam

I have an old Logitech Quickcam Express - the one that looks like this:

[image: Logitech Quickcam Express]

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro running Catalina, and I'd like (if possible) to use the webcam with it.  If I plug it in, I can see it in System Information:

[image: Screenshot from System Information]

...but I can't use it in Photo Booth nor in Google Meets in Chrome (which is where I'd actually like to use it).  Is there anything I can do so that I can use the webcam with my Mac?

Comment: Never tried it with that camera, but [Webcam Settings](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) runs on Catalina & works well for my HD Pro 920. No demo unfortunately, as it's App Store only.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks.  According to their website, "Your USB webcam must be working on your Mac properly (function normally with FaceTime, iChat/Messages, and Skype) before it can be used with Webcam Settings."  So probably not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not trying to be flippant, but I haven't seen that camera since the waning years of the 20th century. (It was released in 1999, BTW.) According to this [FAQ page at Logitech](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360025335453--FAQ-QuickCam-Express), it is unsupported 'on the Macintosh platform'. It will not work on a USB3 port, and there are no macOS drivers. We use a number of these [Logitech webcams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LXCDPPK) in classrooms and they are amazingly good.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking as long as the webcam is a *[standard USB video device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class)*, it will work as those drivers are included with macOS.

However, those vintage webcams required Logitech drivers to be installed as it was a [DSC WIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition) device per [C|Net](https://download.cnet.com/Logitech-QuickCam-Express/3000-18489_4-68674.html) so it needed a Mac specific driver.  What you’re seeing is that the webcam is detected and identified, it just doesn’t have the proper drivers to work.